# [Windows XP]: Is there a shortcut/etc to send a window to another screen?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

I usually use two or more screens (extended desktop) while working on my PCs. I'd like to have an shortcut to move a window to another screen quickly without using the mouse / without dragging it there.
Is there a feature in Win XP, which I can use for that?

Note: As I cannot install custom software at work, i'd prefer a way which doesn't need any additional tool. If there are only third-party tools to acchieve this, please name them anyway - I could use them at least at home.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, that Win 7 supports this feature: SHIFT + WIN + Arrow allows to send windows to other screens. As I'll get a new laptop running Win 7 soon, it's not too bad, that XP doesn't support this.

http://www.technize.com/some-great-windows-7-shortcuts-you-never-knew-before/

Sadly, I have to deal with XP at work a *bit* longer.

Answer (score 0):

[MultiMonitor](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) will "Add a Move to Monitor button to windows applications (XP)."

Comment: Why didn't you specify the product's full name and so saved me some minutes? I deleted my answer.

Comment: There is only one program called MultiMonitor (Google it), and
I brought the same quote you did, it's not enough?

Comment: Well, evidently it wasn't enough :)